# C++ write char array to file with padding

Tags: c++, char

I would like to output a file which is readable like database concept. 
What I expect is:

```
Name[10]  ContactNo[15]  GENDER[10]
====================================
Johnny    +60123456789   MALE      
Emily     +69876543210   FEMALE    
Jason     +61535648979   MALE
```

And i attempt to do this with:

```
char name[10],contact[15],gender[10];

//user input here//

ofstream myfile("contact.txt");
myfile>>name>>contact>>gender;
```

but all string in output file is concatenate without any space. Any idea that i can do that? I try to do this in order for when i read data from file with exactly width and put them into variable, is it a wrong concept? Or any suggestion?

Comment: Set adjustfield and width on output stream. E.g. myfile.width(100);

Comment: You should look at [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of stream manipulators [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) will do what you want:

```
myfile << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
       << std::setw(10) << name
       << std::setw(15) << contact
       << std::setw(10) << gender;
```

`setfill` lets you specify the character used for filling. [`std::left`, `std::internal` and `std::right`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) specify where the fill characters go.

Answer (score 0):

I would include `<stdio.h>` and use `printf()`

```
printf ( "%10s %15s %10s\n", name, contact, gender );
```

That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the symbol `\t` between the values. `\t` insert a tab. Then, you have to write:

```
myfile>>name>>"\t">>contact>>"\t">>gender;
```

Comment: I would not recommend this, `'\t'` is a pain in the bum. Amongst other things, consider if the difference in length between two lines is more than 4 characters (or 8, or whatever, which is another issue).